# Queries collections with spring data and querydsl

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I have the following domain model:

```java
@Entity
public class Sample {
  // id and other stuff
  private boolean deleted;
  private Set<Occurrence> occurrences;
  // Constructors, getter and setter
}

@Entity
public class Occurrence {
  // id and other stuff
  private boolean deleted;
  private Classification classification;
  // Constructors, getter and setter
}

@Entity
public class Classification {
   private int id;
   // other stuff
}
```

I want to find with QueryDSL and Spring Data JPA all Samples which are not deleted and contain an occurrence witch is not deleted and contains a classification with the id 47.

I allready have a BooleanExpression for the not deleted samples: `qSample.deleted.isFalse()` and a SubQuery for the not delted occurrence which has a certain classification id:

```
JPASubQuery occurrenceSubQuery = new JPASubQuery();
QOccurrence qOccurrence = QOccurrence.occurrence;
occurrenceSubQuery.from().where(
       qOccurrence.in(qSample.occurrences),
       qOccurrence.deleted.isFalse(),
       qOccurrence.classification.id
         .eq(queryId));
```

What's missing is: how to bring these parts together to a predicate for the spring data repository?

Regards

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`com.mysema.query.support.Expressions.allOf(...)`

or

`a.and(b).and(c)...`

Comment: I've tried the Expressions.allOff(...) approach, but it returns me all not deleted sample which have an occurrence witch is not deleted and an occurrence which has the correct classification. But I need the sample with an occurrence with the correct classification which is not deleted.